# Double-escaping regex from inside a Groovy expression

Tags: regex, string, groovy, escaping, double-quotes

**Note**: I had to simplify my actual use case to spare SO a lot of backstory. So if your first reaction to this question is: *why would you ever do this*, trust me, I just need to.

I'm trying to write a Groovy expression that replaces double-quotes ("`"`") that appear in a string with single-quotes ("`'`").

```
// BEFORE: Replace my "double" quotes with 'single' quotes.
String toReplace = "Replace my \"double-quotes\" with 'single' quotes.";

// Wrong: compiler error
String replacerExpression = "toReplace.replace(""", "'");";

Binding binding = new Binding();
binding.setVariable("toReplace", toReplace);
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding);

// AFTER: Replace my 'double' quotes with 'single' quotes.
String replacedString = (String)shell.evaluate(replacerExpression);
```

The problem is, I'm getting a compile error on the line where I assign `replacerExpression`:

> Syntax error on token ""toReplace.replace("", { expected

I think it's because I need to escape the string that contains the double-quote character (""") but since it's a string-inside-a-string, I'm not sure how to properly escape it here. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

You need to escape the quote within quotes in this line:

```
String replacerExpression = "toReplace.replace(""", "'");";
```

The string will be evaluated twice: once as a string literal, and once as a script.  This means you have to escape it with a backslash, and escape the backslash too.  Also, with the embedded quotes, it'll be much more readable if you use triple quotes.

Try this (in groovy):

```
String replacerExpression = """toReplace.replace("\\"", "'");""";
```

In Java, you're stuck with using backslashes to escape all the quotes and the embedded backslash:

```
String replacerExpression = "toReplace.replace(\"\\\"\", \"\'\");";
```

Comment: Thanks @ataylor (+1) but your suggestion produces the following compiler rrors: `Multiple markers at this line
 - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable
 - String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote
 - Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Assignment
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete Statement
 - Syntax error on tokens, ( expected instead`

Comment: @IAmYourFaja The second solution to use `"""` works flawless. How are you running the script?

Comment: Oh, I see.  The outer code is Java, not groovy.  I've updated the answer to show how to quote it in Java as well.

Answer (score 1):

Triple-quotes work well, but one can also use single-quoted string to specify a double-quote, and a double-quoted string for a single-quote.

Consider this:

```
String toReplace = "Replace my \"double-quotes\" with 'single' quotes." 

// key line:
String replacerExpression = """toReplace.replace('"', "'");"""

Binding binding = new Binding(); binding.setVariable("toReplace", toReplace)
GroovyShell shell = new GroovyShell(binding)

String replacedString = (String)shell.evaluate(replacerExpression)
```

That is, after the string literal evaluation, this is evaluated in the Groovy shell:

```
toReplace.replace('"', "'");
```

If that is too hard on the eyes, replace the "key line" above with another style (using slashy strings):

```
String ESC_DOUBLE_QUOTE = /'"'/ 
String ESC_SINGLE_QUOTE = /"'"/ 
String replacerExpression = """toReplace.replace(${ESC_DOUBLE_QUOTE}, ${ESC_SINGLE_QUOTE});"""
```

Comment: Thanks @Michael Easter (+1) but your suggestion (after you write "Consider this:"...) produces the following compiler errors: `Multiple markers at this line
 - Invalid character constant
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete LocalVariableDeclarationStatement`

Comment: The line formerly used after "Consider this" was intended to be placed in the original script. I have updated the post so that the full example is listed after "Consider this".

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) to solve this kind of problems, instead of messing your head to tackle the escaping of quotes.

I have put up a [solution](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/1105001) using groovy console. Please see if that helps.